# Crazy CPU fan runs at ~5500rpm while temp is OK

Tags: windows-7, cpu, fan, speedfan

A single picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: monitor_screen.png]

AMD FX-4300 is my CPU, Windows 7 is my OS, my Motherboard is a ASRock 970 Pro3 R2.0.

Why are the RPM at such a high level?

Comment: Is it loud? Those reading can be inaccurate sometimes. If that number is correct then it should sound like a jet engine.

Comment: PS: tag RPM is the redhat package manager.

Comment: You have to ask a Question to ask a Question, I edited in the "such high level?" line, if this is not your question, please pardon me and edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your Temperature Readings? 14°C. This tells me that your readings are wrong. So maybe your Fan readings are wrong as well. However, stock CPU-Fans can get really loud and 5400rpm is nothing too unusual when there is high load = high temperature. You should be able to hear 5400rpm. Idle rpm is around 800-1500rpm for stock fans.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is saying here - check the actual values if you can. 14 degrees is very cold for a CPU, unless you have a specialized system the CPU will never be colder than the room it is in.

Again, as said, the fan will be very loud when running at 5500 RPM, unless you can hear it spooling up it's probably not running that fast.

It's likely that at least one of these numbers is wrong. Try swapping that fan for another one (one of the ones that's idling at a reasonable speed). Try another hardware monitoring program and see if the numbers are the same, or boot up into bios and look at your CPU temp there.